# can multiple scripts use inotifywait to watch the same file simultaneously?

Tags: linux, inotify, inotifywait

Is there anything about the nature of inotify's `inotifywait` that would result in unpredictable behavior (or predictable problems) when running two or more scripts that each uses `inotifywait` to watch the same file or set of files?

Or is it safe/ok, technically, to have multiple scripts using `inotifywait` on the same files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is safe. [inotify](https://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) is a Linux kernel API which allows concurency.

Comment: Thanks for editing that to say "it is safe".  I have to wait a few minutes before I'm allowed to accept it ;)